# Flutter: how can I get data from firebase with a foreach that recovers the id from the documents

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I have this code and `List<Widget>> productRelated` returns null or [] and i need this data for the function `getRelatedProductsWidget`

```
Future<List<Widget>> getRelatedProductWidgets(List<dynamic> eans) async {
    final List<Widget> productsRelated = [];

    eans.forEach((e) async {
      DocumentSnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection('products').document(e).get();
      Product product = Product.fromMap(result);
      productsRelated.add(new ListTile(title: Text(product.productName)));
    }); 
    return productsRelated;
}


Widget getRelatedProductsWidget(List<dynamic> relatedProducts) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getRelatedProductWidgets(relatedProducts),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List<Widget> products = snapshot.data ?? [];
        print(products);
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: products.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return products[index];
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I'll be very greatful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method returns an empty list because you do not tell the code to wait for the asychronous calls to finish before returning the variable. So, essentially, the variable is initialized (or declared), some asynchronous calls are started, and then the variable is returned.

You can use "x = await Future.wait( y.map( method to map element to database call ) ); return x;" or use something like "return y.forEach( ... ).then( ... return x);" to return the result of that chain.

Comment: can u add an example pls??

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
await Future.wait(eans.map((e) async {
    DocumentSnapshot result =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('products').document(e).get();
    product.add(Product.fromMap(result))  
}));
```

Comment: Nice, sorry I didn't format it better (on my phone on the bus), feel free to mark your answer as accepted too